# Exporting SNAP S1 preprocessing model as Python script

Tags: python, sentinel-1, sentinel-snap

I am new to SNAP and Sentinel 1. I am using SNAP for preprocessing of the Sentinel-1 image, however, I am dealing with large S1 datasets so the preprocessing time is long.

Can I export the model to a python script and start preprocessing it in Google collab?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You cannot directory export it from SNAP, but there are libraries in Python which allow you to easily create and run it.

- [snapista](https://snap-contrib.github.io/snapista/) *recommended*
- [pyroSAR](https://github.com/johntruckenbrodt/pyroSAR/blob/master/docs/general/snap.rst)
- [snappy](https://gist.github.com/braunfuss/41caab61817fbae71a25bba82a02a8c0)

Answer (score 0):

You could use high level libraries such as [EOReader](https://github.com/sertit/eoreader) to pre-process directly your data (with SNAP under the hood):

```py
from eoreader.reader import Reader
from eoreader.bands import VV


# Open the Sentinel-1 product
prod = Reader().open("S1A_IW_GRDH_1SDV_20191215T060906_20191215T060931_030355_0378F7_3696.zip")

# Load VV band
vv_band = prod.load(VV)[VV]
```

More information on SAR data are available in this [notebook](https://eoreader.readthedocs.io/en/latest/notebooks/SAR.html).

> Disclaimer: I am the maintainer of EOReader.

Comment: You have posted this or a similar answer several times. In case this is your development or you are associated to it, please add a disclaimer. Otherwise this may be detected as spam.